# Issues installing python module with pip

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I am using python 3.9 running windows10 x86-64. Just after trying to install the python module 'Pygame' it stopped due to an error. I am new to coding in python and a result am unsure as to what to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: FYI from [ask]: **_DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc._ - copy or type the text into the question.**

Answer (score 0):

There unfortunately [is no binary package of Pygame for Python 3.9 on Windows yet](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files), and your install process is failing on trying to build Pygame from sources.

I'd recommend downgrading to Python 3.8 for the time being if you don't want to wait for that to happen, as trying to install all the build dependencies on Windows will likely be very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no update of **pygame available for Python 3.9**, thus you will have to stick with **Python 3.8 in** order to use the module.

You can simply create a **virtual environment** with the **3.8 Python version** if you don't want to downgrade entirely.

After doing so, try to run

```
$ pip install pygame
```

again.